# move a div on parabolic path with increasing size simultaneously using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to this concept. I have also tried certain libraries but they are not as much perfect for my problem.
Please help!

this is what i have done till now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
#cont{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 36px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button2').click(function(){
        $('#cont').animate({height: '+=500',width :'+=500',opacity: 0.4, marginLeft: "1in",marginTop: "2in",}, 1500);

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="click">
<div id="cont">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have tried? you should also show that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it is a place to get help with problems you are having. With that in mind please edit your question to include code that you have attempted so far and the problems you have with it otherwise the question will be closed and deleted.

Comment: hey @ChrisSpittles, now provide the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#bezier').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    stop();
    tween($.curve.bezier, {
        x: 0,
        y: $canvas[0].height,
        points: [
            [0, $canvas[0].height / 2],
            [$canvas[0].width * 0.5, 0],
            [$canvas[0].width * 0.9, $canvas[0].height],
            [$canvas[0].width, $canvas[0].height/ 2]
        ]
    });
});
```

you should use your parabolic equation to move the div in parabolic path.